# How can I use soft deleted with relation

Tags: php, laravel

I use eloquent with soft delete .I'm getting error because of my query still select data that already use softdelete here is my model

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles, SoftDeletes;
    protected $guard_name = 'web';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

for example I've 100 user and I deleted 1 user with softdelete . then I try to

```
$a = User::all();
dd($a);
```

I get 99 user . It works! but after I use it relation It doest work here what I do

This is my Parent table and Model

table

```
 |id|user_id|parent_id|
```

**Note** : user_id and parent_id are FK in user.id table

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'parent';
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}


$getParent = Parent::with('user')->get();
```

when I `dd($getParent);` why I still get null data from user_id that I already use soft deleted ?

**UPDATE** model User  : after I put whereNull I still getting user that I alredy soft deleted

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->whereNull('users.deleted_at');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I *think* is going on...

With soft delete the ondelete event doesn't work (meaning that related models is not deleted). I'm not sure if that changed in later versions of Laravel, but I don't think so. Also deleting User would still not affect the parent model, since you haven't defined the relationship between User and Parent (in the User model), only between Parent and User.

Try defining the relationship in User and then override the boot() function, that sits in the Model class. (This is untested code, but something like this should do the job)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles, SoftDeletes;
    protected $guard_name = 'web';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    // Override Model boot function
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function ($users) {
            foreach ($users->parents()->get() as $parent) {
                $parent->delete();
            }
        });
    }

    // Define relationship with parent model
    public function parents()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Parent');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this work but Is there anyway to override the boot() function, in Parent model? because in many query I start with Parent model

Comment: @TryHardz How do you mean that you start with the parent model? If you're deleting a parent model, you should probably not delete the user model from that anyway, since it's a one-to-many relationship. I don't know how your code looks. But if there's a case where you want to delete the User from the parent, just get the user model from the parent, and then call the delete function on the user. $parent = Parent::find($parentId); $user = User:.find($parent->user_id); $user->delete(); or something like that.

Comment: You could of course override the boot() function in Parent and add code to delete related User models. But I would, personally, consider that bad practice. It would feel kind of counter intuitive if a model that belongs to another would delete the model it belongs to, and then that model would in turn delete the first models siblings.

Comment: so I cant restore this data when I alredy use  static::delet right?

Comment: @TryHardz If your models are set to soft delete, you should be able to restore it

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

```
...
    public function customerAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Addresses::class, "id", "id_address")->withTrashed();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a constraint on the Eager Load:

```
public function groups()
{

    return $this
    ->belongsToMany('Group')
    ->whereNull('group_user.deleted_at') // Table `group_user` has column `deleted_at`
    ->withTimestamps(); // Table `group_user` has columns: `created_at`, `updated_at`

}
```

Instead of HARD deleting the relationship using:

```
User::find(1)->groups()->detach();
```

You should use something like this to SOFT delete instead:

```
DB::table('group_user')
->where('user_id', $user_id)
->where('group_id', $group_id)
->update(array('deleted_at' => DB::raw('NOW()')));
```

Comment: after I put $this->belongsTo('App\User')->whereNull('users.deleted_at'); I still getting same value